# PHP session should not expire until user logs out

Tags: php

On my website, sometimes user gets logged out abruptly without even clicking the 'log out' button. Why is this happening? I have checked my default settings,

```
session.gc_divisor      1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  0   0
```

Everything seems pretty ok because the garbage collector is only started with a probability of session.gc_probability divided by session.gc_divisor. And using the default values for that options (0 and 1000 respectively), the chance is 0%. So why users are getting logged out? Please tell me how can I implement the functionality where user should not get logged out until he/she clicks on 'log out' button i.e session_start() should not go for garbage collection until user clicks on 'log out' button?

If I include this below code in every script, will it work?

```
<?php

   ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 30*60);
   session_start();

?>
```

Comment: Does the user ever get logged out before 24 minutes? Are you using your own session handler (e.g. database) or the default one?

Comment: Yes, sometimes user gets logged out before 24 minutes. I'm using the default session handler.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on shared hosting?  I had the same problem on shared hosting before where the session files were being stored in a default shared directory that was randomly being cleared and removing the session files.  I got around it by moving my session files to another directory.

Try saving sessions to another location that you have some control over using `session_save_path("path/to/another/folder")` and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. I'm checking this out. I have changed my php.ini to this, will it work?

    session.gc_probability = 1
    session.gc_divisor = 1000
    session.gc_maxlifetime = 28800

In this way garbage collector will run only after 8 hours. Even if the user is inactive on the site, it shouldn't expire the session but if the user closes the browser window or logs out, session will expire.

Comment: @user3484291 Hopefully it does.  As I said in my answer, this was the work around for a shared host provider that was by default storing the session files in the `tmp` directory and then clearing it out rather aggressively.  I also used some `ini_set()` calls changing sessions parameters as well.  I didn't actually make any changes to php.ini as I don't have access to it.